# Why does my code sometimes saves both mp3 and mp4 files (Python, PyTube, OS)?

Tags: python, operating-system, pytube

I wrote a Python code to download audio from YouTube within a for loop.

```
       search_kw = tracks[i+1]['Artist'] + '+' + tracks[i+1]['Track Title']

        print('Preparing ' + tracks[i+1]['Artist'] + '-' + tracks[i+1]['Track Title'])
        
        spot_track_length = tracks[i+1]['Duration (minutes)']

        search_kw = search_kw.replace(' ','+')

        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + unidecode(search_kw))
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        video_ids = list(set(video_ids))
        
        len_dif = 999
        
        for k in range(len(video_ids)):
            try:
                temp_song_yt_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[k]
                yt_track_length = YouTube(temp_song_yt_link).length/60
                yt_track_title = YouTube(temp_song_yt_link).streams[0].title
            except:
                continue
            
            if yt_track_title.find(tracks[i+1]['Track Title']) != -1:
                if np.abs(spot_track_length - yt_track_length) < len_dif:
                    len_dif = np.abs(spot_track_length - yt_track_length)
                    if len_dif < 1e-2:
                        song_yt_link = temp_song_yt_link
                        break
                
        selected_video = YouTube(song_yt_link).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

        output_path = 'file path'
        # audio = selected_video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').first()
        # audio.download(output_path=output_path)
        
        print('Downloading ' + tracks[i+1]['Artist'] + '-' + tracks[i+1]['Track Title'])
        audio = selected_video.download(output_path=output_path)
        # extras.Convert(audio,'mp3',add_meta=True)

        title = audio.title
        
        print('Saving ' + tracks[i+1]['Artist'] + '-' + tracks[i+1]['Track Title'])
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(audio)
        new_file = base + '.mp3'
        os.rename(audio, new_file)
        
        print('Saved ' + tracks[i+1]['Artist'] + '-' + tracks[i+1]['Track Title'])
```

I am noticing that when it downloads, sometimes it will save both an mp3 and mp4 (both audio only) of a YouTube video. (Edit) After debugging, I noticed that the code will download the .mp4 file when it somehow does not download the song it is search for (example Scream by Michael Jackson gets downloaded as a mp3, then as an mp4 when the loop is searching for Big L-The Enemy (feat. Fat Joe)).

Is there a reason for this, and how can I prevent this from happening (outside of writing an extra code after the fact to check for mp4 files and deleting them if detected)?

Comment: Check my answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76790761/unable-to-create-a-directory-and-place-file-in-it-with-python-with-pytube/76934956#76934956