# Unable to create a directory and place file in it with python with Pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to use pytube to download a playlist and have the videos placed in a newly created directory named after the playlists name on youtube. So far, my code creates the new directory with the correct name, but it does not place the downloaded videos in that new directory. The files are nowhere to be found.

Here is my code:

```
from pytube import Playlist
import os

p = Playlist(input("Enter the URL of the playlist you want to download: \n>> "))
print(f'Downloading: {p.title}')
#make directory based on name of the playlist

#destination = '/home/jason/Music'

destination = os.makedirs(f'/home/jason/Music/{p.title}')


for video in p.videos:
    out_file = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path=destination) #destination should include created directory
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = base + '.mp3'
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)
```

Comment: Does the `.download` method work at all?

Comment: What does `print(out_file)` show?

Answer (score 1):

```
destination = os.makedirs(f'/home/jason/Music/{p.title}')
```

as i know
this the os.makedirs() returns "None" a path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote to download every audio from the videos in a yt playlist and convert to proper mp3s.

**I wrote it using Python 3.9 and it is only tested it under Windows.**

**Please take note that it requires FFMPEG for the mp3 conversion** (you must have it installed in PATH or have the executable ffmpeg.exe in the directory where you launch the script)

Hope it helps and let me know if you have any questions!

```
import os
import subprocess
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist

#PLAYLIST PART
playlist = Playlist(input("Enter the URL of the playlist you want to download: \n>> "))
print(playlist.title)

#DIRECTORY CREATION PART
newPath = os.getcwd()+"\\"+playlist.title
#if the directory does not exist, create it
if not os.path.exists(newPath):
    os.makedirs(newPath)
#move to the directory
os.chdir(newPath)

#info
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
print(len(playlist.video_urls))

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    #DOWNLOAD AND CONVERSION PART
    print(url)
    yt = YouTube(url)
    
    #get the video title
    titolo = yt.streams[0].title
    video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    new_file = titolo + '.mp3'
    #audio download
    out_file = video.download(output_path='')
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    
    #STOP HERE IF YOU JUST NEED THE .mp4
    old_file = base + '.mp4'
    new_file = base + '.mp3'
    #conversion with ffmpeg to .mp3
    try:
        subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", f"{old_file}", "-y", f"{new_file}"], check=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        #something is wrong! maybe the file already exists or a ffmpeg related error?
        os.remove(old_file)
        continue
    os.remove(old_file)
    
    # result of success
    print(yt.title + " has been successfully downloaded.")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work, tested in python 3.11.4 with pytube version 15.0.0 (with the cipher in the pytube lib replaced by https://github.com/oncename/pytube/blob/master/pytube/cipher.py).

```
import os
from pytube import Playlist

if __name__ == "__main__":

  p = Playlist(input("Enter the URL of the playlist you want to download: \n>> "))
  playlistFolder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), p.title) #Creates the directory path as a variable
  os.makedirs(playlistFolder) #Creates the directory based upon the variable

 for video in p.videos:
    out_file = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path=playlistFolder) 
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = base + '.mp3'
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)
```